# why np.einsum() can run on GPU if the arrays are defined in GPU?

Tags: python, gpu, google-colaboratory

I recently realize that as long as variables (or arrays) are defined in GPU, numpy functions run as fast as cupys. I couldn't find out a way to monitor whether numpy functions are actually executed on GPU. if someone had similar experience, please share your answer. Thanks.

I am using google colabpro GPU runtime.

below are two sets of code:

```
import numpy as np
import cupy as cp
```

set 1:

```
a = np.random.randn(500, 500, 500)
b = np.random.randn(500, 500, 500)   
start_time = time.time()
for i in range(1): 
  c = np.einsum('ijk,ikm->ijm', a, b)        
end_time = time.time()
print('forwar gpu time')
print(end_time - start_time)

forwar gpu time
55.88586902618408
```

set 2:

```
a = cp.random.randn(500, 500, 500)   # change to cupy
b = cp.random.randn(500, 500, 500)   # change to cupy
start_time = time.time()
for i in range(1): 
  c = np.einsum('ijk,ikm->ijm', a, b)    # remain numpy    
end_time = time.time()
print('forwar gpu time')
print(end_time - start_time)

forwar gpu time
0.0009937286376953125
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at a bit of `numpy.einsum` in `einsumfunc.py`:

```
@array_function_dispatch(_einsum_dispatcher, module='numpy')
def einsum(*operands, out=None, optimize=False, **kwargs):
```

Well, that decorator looks promising; you are indeed describing a function *dispatching* on argument types. Let's look at a bit of `array_function_dispatch` in `overrides.py`

```
def array_function_dispatch(dispatcher, module=None, verify=True,
                            docs_from_dispatcher=False):
    """Decorator for adding dispatch with the __array_function__ protocol.
    See NEP-18 for example usage.
```

And that takes us to the far more readable [NEP-18](https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0018-array-function-protocol.html): "We propose the `__array_function__` protocol, to allow arguments of NumPy functions to define how that function operates on them..." So NumPy functions check `__array_function__` or `__array_ufunc__` (NEP-13) of its arguments.

CuPy defines `cupy.ndarray.__array_function__` in `core.pyx` (a Cython file). It looks for the NumPy function's name in the similarly organized CuPy module and calls it on the arguments. So when you called `np.einsum(...)`, it ended up finding `cp.einsum(...)` anyway:

```
cdef class ndarray:
...
...
...
    def __array_function__(self, func, types, args, kwargs):
        try:
            module = functools.reduce(
                getattr, func.__module__.split('.')[1:], cupy)
            cupy_func = getattr(module, func.__name__)
        except AttributeError:
            return NotImplemented
        if cupy_func is func:
            # avoid NumPy func
            return NotImplemented
        for t in types:
            if t not in _HANDLED_TYPES:
                return NotImplemented
        return cupy_func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks BatWannaBe, this makes a lot of sense. I also realized that, any python operators, like "+" or " * ", also get interpreted or compiled as GPU executable codes.

Comment: If the answer fully addresses your question, you should resolve the post by accepting the answer (clicking the check mark under the vote counter so it becomes green) so stackoverflow knows.